# How do I prevent a publishing workflow from running in certain subfolders in a library?

Tags: 2013, workflow, reporting-services

I have a library in SharePoint set up with a basic "publishing workflow" so the folder owner has to approve new documents that are added. This works fine.

I'm also running SSRS in SharePoint Integrated mode. Users would like to be able to set up SSRS reports with subscriptions to deliver reports to a subfolder in this library but the approval workflow should not run in that folder as it will have many daily reports. I don't see any way to prevent the workflow from running in a subfolder. Am I missing something or is there no way to override this?

[SOLUTION] - I was able to create a subfolder called "NoApprovalNeeded". I then copied the default "Publishing Approval" in SharePoint Designer and added the steps shown below. (The IF and the 2 steps below, with the subfolder name highlighted in red)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the workflow check for this immediately. So technically it will run on these, but will stop before the approval section is hit.

```
- If Path contains /library/subfolder
  - Stop Workflow
```

Comment: This is something I would do in SharePoint Designer?

Comment: Yes, you would have to change the workflow so that you aren't using a publishing workflow out of the box, but rather building it in SharePoint Designer for more flexibility and control. You can perform the same exact functions as the publishing workflow you have now.

Comment: Great. Thanks! I was hoping to keep custom workflows out of the equation, no matter how simple, but I do have some basic familiarity with it and will look into this if that's the only way.