# How to have SSRS subscription delivery trigger workflow in a document library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, reporting-services

I have SSRS running in SharePoint Integrated Mode in SharePoint 2013. I have a subscription on a report set up to deliver to a document library that has a publishing approval workflow (SharePoint 2010 workflow - 2013 is not installed). When the subscription runs, the workflow fails to start with "workflow was canceled by System Account" and "workflow failed to start".

- "Creating a new item will start this workflow" is enabled
- Manually putting a file in the folder works because it is triggered by my account
- Incoming mail is NOT enabled on this library
- Ran "stsadm -o setproperty -pn declarativeworkflowautostartonemailenabled -pv true", even though mail is NOT enabled
- I have deactivated/reactivated all workflow services

Is there any way to get SSRS to deliver the reports in a different way that will trigger the workflow?

I see the following in the ULS logs:

> RunWorkflow: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: 
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPNoCodeXomlCompiler.LoadXomlAssembly(SPWorkflowAssociation association, SPWeb web)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWinOeHostServices.LoadDeclarativeAssembly(SPWorkflowAssociation association, Boolean fallback)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWinOeHostServices.CreateInstance(SPWorkflow workflow)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWinOeEngine.RunWorkflow(SPWorkflowHostService host, SPWorkflow workflow, Collection`1 events, TimeSpan timeOut)
>
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager.RunWorkflowElev(SPWorkflow workflow, Collection`1 events, SPWorkflowRunOptionsInternal runOptions)

Comment: Somewhat ironically, the workflow I am trying to get to run is one that will skip the approval process for files in a certain folder as shown here.  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/228810/20804

Answer (score 2):

What account is being used by SSRS to save the report to the library? Declarative (SPD) workflows will not auto-start when using a system account.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sowmyancs/2009/03/31/issue-with-sharepoint-designer-workflow-to-start-under-system-acccount/

This can also be caused by a workflow related file/form being checked out. See here:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointdevelopersupport/2015/03/11/failed-on-start-in-spd-workflow/

Comment: The workflow is not checked out, so the first link seems more likely. In my scenario, the same domain account runs everything, including the SSRS app pool. I have seen that workaround, but it's not clear. It's for SharePoint 2007, and it doesn't specify which service account needs to be changed. The SSRS app pool? Why would changing from one domain account to another change anything? Does it just need to be different from a certain other app pool's service account?

Comment: The intent was to prevent administrators doing data maintenance from triggering workflows. I think it mainly needs to be anything other than the SharePoint farm account. I'll do some checking...

Comment: Did you happen to check in on this? I've spent dozens of hours on this, and can't get anything working. This is holding up a big project. I am about ready to create a separate document library for every department for these generated SSRS reports, but that seems foolish. Thank you!

Comment: Can you change the service account for SSRS to something other than the service account used for SharePoint and do a test?

Comment: I go to "Manage Service Applications" in CA, and then click the SSRS service. From there, I click "Execution Account" and key in another domain account different from the SharePoint service accounts. I stop/start the service, and then ran a subscription on one of the SSRS reports. The report is generated in the target library, but still shows the same errors. Is that the method you were thinking of for changing the service account?

Comment: Which ever account is being used to save the report to the library.

Comment: Just in case... I'm assuming you have searched for "workflow was canceled by System Account" to see some of the common causes.

Comment: Yup, I've tried every "solution" I've come across with no luck. I am surprised that this does not seem to be common functionality that people use.